# Configure intellij bundled nginx to accept remote connections

Tags: nginx, intellij-idea, embedded-jetty

I'm using Intellij 14.1.5 and running a local google app engine development server. I want to see how my pages look on mobile and tablets screens. I've been using Chrome's device emulation screen options but have found some meaningful differences between how Chrome's device emulation renders a page and how an actual device renders the same page.

So I'd like to access my pages directly on my Intellij dev server on my local network to experiment with the css and media directives. Intellij is running an nginx server. It's not clear if this nginx server is bundled into Intellij or if it uses an external instance of nginx.

I've only found one nginx.conf file on my entire system (Mac OS X) and configured it as per below but the Intellij dev server is still refusing remote connections. My firewall is turned off. Ideally I'd like to only accept only local network outside connections, i.e. 192.168.*.*.

Has anyone had any luck getting an Intellij bundled dev server to accept non-localhost connections? Thanks in advance for any insights.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    # server_name  localhost;
   ...
}
```

Update: Upon further investigation, I was mislead by error messages in my browser being generated by nginx. The bundled server with Intellij and Google App Engine is Jetty.

On my Mac OS system there are jetty config files in:
appengine-java-sdk/lib/java-managed-vm/appengine-java-vmruntime/etc/
appengine-java-sdk/lib/jetty-base-sdk/etc/jetty.xml

And the key seems to be setting the default host value to 0.0.0.0. Despite that it's not working yet. I suspect nginx is running by default on the same port 8080 and may be causing a conflict or that my local network may be interfering.

Comment: I really don't think that IntelliJ bundles Nginx.  Are you sure you don't have a server running locally?

Comment: @Makoto I agree, I don't think the nginx is bundled and Intellij is likely leveraging my local nginx instance. If you comment out server_name in nginx.conf that should open up the server to remote connections yet I'm still getting "Forbidden" when accessing remotely or locally with 192.168.0.9 (which is my local network IP).

Comment: No...commenting out the server name doesn't necessarily open it up to remote connections.  That's governed by your firewall and if any service is running through that port.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for that tip...in case others come across the same problem this is where I read that:  http://serverfault.com/questions/279201/nginx-configuration-make-accessible-from-outside-localhost